# Can't highlighting only one word exact on the one sentence

Tags: org-mode, highlighting

Given:
Linux Mint 20.2,
Emacs 27.2

Q: E.g. "Hello, how are you?" Suppose whole sentence has foreground color = white.
And I want to change color (e.g to red) of only word "Hello".
A: There is a general way of highlighting a word or regular expression using any face you want.
Try *M-x highlight-regexp* (bound to M-s h r). It prompts you for the text to highlight and
then it gives you the option to pick any face you want to use. To get a list of all faces,
use **M-x list-faces-display**. Once you have highlighted all occurrences of a word,
you can remove the highlights with **M-x unhighlight-regexp** (bound to M-s h u).

```
 Here result:
```

[image]

Q: Yes, but **M-x highlight-regexp** is highlighting  word "**Hello**" in the **whole text**.
E.g. if word "**Hello**" occur **3 times** in the whole buffer it will be highlighting.
But I need to highlighting **only one word** "Hello" **exact on the sentence** *"Hello, how are you?"* after **Here result:**.
Is it possible on org mode?

P.S. The ideal scenario is to select some region and highlighting only it

Comment: [This](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/30533/highlight-region) suggesting the highlight library might be useful

Comment: See [Text properties](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Text-Properties.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Highlight region](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/30533/highlight-region)

Comment: Would [narrowing](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Narrowing.html) (even if not ideal) work for your goals maybe ? And as a *fun* workaround (sorry for the noise..) we might use `query-replace`: a). Mark region, b). M-% to call `query-replace`, c) Choose/write "Query replacing Hello with Hello" <RET>, d) See Hello highlighted in the region (with the replacement artifacts of course :)